# How to write when you're comparing dates

Tags: technical, dates

I want to express in a technical specification document the outcome when comparing two dates. In programming language I can simply say if DateA is smaller than DateB but when translating this to regular language I'm not sure how this is written in English (not my main language).

For some reason saying that

> DateA is earlier than DateB

sounds strange to me. That's how I currently have it written.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry DateA < DateB should be the correct one. So "earlier" is what we have in the document now. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

"Date A ***precedes*** Date B".

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precede)

***precede***

*transitive verb*

: to be earlier than

For the other reason of my recommendation look at the [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Date%20is%20earlier%20than%2C%20date%20precedes%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdate%20precedes%3B%2Cc0).

According to the graph "to be earlier than" is not appropriate in this context.